# Pygame plays sounds at wrong pitch

Tags: python, pygame

When trying to play the file `Jingle_Lose_01.wav` from https://opengameart.org/content/8-bit-sound-effects-library (converted to ogg) through pygame, the sound comes out much lower pitched than normal.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('test.ogg')
sound.play()
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you play the converted file using other software? Maybe the conversion is causing it.

Comment: I already tried that. The file plays perfectly with other software.

Comment: In that case it sounds—no pun intended—like a `pygame` bug. Report it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the hertz to 44100

`ffmpeg -i test.ogg -ar 44100 out.ogg`

Then verify

`file out.ogg`